# jquery datatable checkbox cell browser back issue

Tags: datatables

I will use a picture and the github project to demonstrate the issue.

[image]

Steps:

1. First, check the checkbox
2. Then click the jump out link
3. Third, click go back
4. At last, what's weird is that the checkbox has been sorted to the bottom, and I can't figure out why.

That's the issue. Thank you and appreciate any help.
[checkout the code on github, just 4 lines of javasript code](https://github.com/leeziwong/jquery-datatable-checkbox-cell-histroy-back-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a name attribute to your checkboxes, that will fix it. Interestingly, an id attribute won't. Strange behavior indeed...

Comment: It's works! Thank's a lot! It seems that name attribute is important for jquery datatable. When you miss it, a lot other issue could happen. Thanks again.

Comment: @seanwong You could accept the answer, if it helped you out. You will earn a nice shiny Scholar badge :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for reminding me. Actually, I have no idea how to accept an answer. I google and read the short instruction, then I did it.